# Happy ending problem – Why not a proof by induction?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, ramsey-theory, polygons

I have been thinking for a while on the [happy ending problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem), looking for approaches to attack the Erdős–Szekeres conjecture: the smallest number of points for which any general position arrangement contains a convex subset of $n$ points is $2^{n-2}+1$.

After reviewing the most recent literature on the problem and the different lines of attack explored, I wonder if it would be worthy to consider the possibility of proving it by induction. The case $n=3$ is almost inmediate to prove, and applying the inductive hypothesis, it is easy to show that some set of $2^{(n+1)-2}+1$ points contains many distinct convex subsets of $n$ points. The tricky part would be to arrange the distinct convex subsets of $n$ points to show that they imply the existence of some convex subset of $n+1$ points.

To illustrate this idea of how the distinct convex subsets of $n$ points could help to show that there exist some convex subset of $n+1$ points, let us asume by inductive hypothesis that the conjecture is true for $n=5$, and  consider a random set $S$ of $2^{4}+1$ points:
[image: 2^4 + 1 points on the plane]

By the inductive hypothesis, each subset of $2^3+1$ points contains a convex subset of $5$ points. Let us choose one of those subsets:
[image: Selected (2^3 + 1)-point subset and pentagon]

To optimize the number of distinct convex pentagons that do not intersect each other in more than some edge, we could continue selecting another subset of $2^3+1$ points, including at most two points forming an edge of the first convex pentagon found, to get (in this case):
[image: Another selected (2^3 + 1)-point subset and pentagon]

It can be already noticed that the two convex pentagons found already restrict the possible locations of the rest of the points of $S$ in order to avoid the existence of a convex subset of $6$ points. If we continue with the same strategy, we can get:
[image: Third subset and pentagon]

With each found convex pentagon, it is more and more evident the existence of a convex hexagon in set $S$. Each of the convex pentagons projects a "convexity zone" where, if located any two points, would guarantee the existence of a convex hexagon:
[image: Convexity zones]

Obviously, this is just a random set and the strategy illustrated does not intend to be the correct one to be able to prove by induction the Erdős–Skezeres conjecture; however, I think it could be worthy to explore the possibility of a proof by induction.

I would appreciate your ideas and thoughts about this possible attack strategy on the problem. Has someone tried to implement it already?

Comment: Have you read https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08657 (which is so far the paper that's come closest to resolving the conjecture)?

Comment: @SamHopkins thanks for the reference! I have read it (diagonally, I must recognize), and it has really interesting ideas. I will take a better look at it to see if some of them are applicable to this line of attack.

Comment: Unicode note:  It's Erdős, not Erdös.  I have edited accordingly.