# Happy ending problem - why not a proof by induction? (cont)

Tags: graph-theory, convex-geometry, ramsey-theory, polygons, erdos

After sharing ideas on [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/396018/172800), I have been thinking for some time on the problem, and I think that a possible way to prove the Erdös-Szekeres conjecture could be structured as follows:

Consider some set $X$ of $2^{n-2}$ points in general position in the plane. We can introduce a coordinate system $\left(x,y\right)$ in the plane, such that $X=\left\{ (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,\left(x_{2^{n-2}}, y_{2^{n-2}}\right)\right\}$, with $x_i \neq x_j \space \forall i,j$ and $x_{1}<x_{2}<\cdots<x_{2^{n-2}}$.

In [1], a subset of points $\left\{(x_{i_1},y_{i_1}), (x_{i_2},y_{i_2}), \ldots, (x_{i_r},y_{i_r})\right\}$  is called an $r$-cup if $x_{i_1}<x_{i_2}<\cdots<x_{i_r}$ and $\frac{y_{i_1}-y_{i_2}}{x_{i_1}-x_{i_2}}<\frac{y_{i_2}-y_{i_3}}{x_{i_2}-x_{i_3}}< \cdots < \frac{y_{i_{r-1}}-y_{i_r}}{x_{i_{r-1}}-x_{i_r}}$, and an $r$-cap if $x_{i_1}<x_{i_2}< \cdots <x_{i_r}$ and $\frac{y_{i_1}-y_{i_2}}{x_{i_1}-x_{i_2}}>\frac{y_{i_2}-y_{i_3}}{x_{i_2}-x_{i_{3}}}> \cdots >\frac{y_{i_{r-1}}-y_{i_r}}{x_{i_{r-1}}-x_{i_r}}$.

Moving forward, we will consider a cup or cap indifferently as a "structure".

I believe that a proof by induction can be constructed based on the following

**Conjecture**

*Every set $X$ of $2^{n-2}$ points in general position in the plane either contains some $n$-structure, or every point in the set belong to $2^{n-2}-1$ structures of $(n-1)$ points.*

I have checked the conjecture for $n<6$ and seems to hold. However, the interesting way to proceed would be using induction. It is almost trivial to check it for $n=3$, and by inductive hypothesis we can assume it for $2^{n-2}$ points. However, the combinatorial knowledge necessary to complete the induction proof of the conjecture (if possible) exceeds my current knowledge.

I guess, based on some experimentation, that the inductive step could be something similar to the following: given the inductive hypothesis, having two distinct sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ of $2^{n-2}$ points in general position in the plane each, such that every point in each set belong to $2^{n-2}-1$ structures of $(n-1)$ points, to avoid generating an $n+1$-structure when (wlog) adding points from $X_2$ into $X_1$, the only possible way is to consider that adding $m$ points from $X_2$ into $X_1$ causes that each point of the new set $X_3=\left\{ (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), \ldots, \left(x_{2^{n-2}},y_{2^{n-2}}\right),\left(x_{2^{n-2}+1},y_{2^{n-2}+1}\right),\left(x_{2^{n-2}+2},y_{2^{n-2}+2}\right),\ldots,\left(x_{2^{n-2}+m},y_{2^{n-2}+m} \right)\right\}$ belong to $2^{n-2}-1+(m-1)$ structures of $n$ points, excepting when $m=2^{n-2}$, that the number of structures of $n$ points grows by $2$ for each point (for a reason that I do not grasp). Thus, when $m=2^{n-2}$ and $X_3=X_1\cup X_2$, each point in $X_3$, which has $2^{n-1}$ points, belongs to $2^{n-1}-1$ structures of $n$ points. However, I do not know (because of my combinatorial limited knowledge) how to prove this.

Incidentally, if this way of proving the conjecture were followed and were correct, it would show a bit more than Erdös-Szekeres conjecture. It would imply that, if some set of $2^{n-2}$ points in general position in the plane does not contain an $n$-structure, then adding $m$ points causes that each point of the new set of $2^{n-2}+m$ points belongs to $2^{n-2}-1+(m-1)$ structures of $n$ points, excepting when $m=2^{n-2}$, that the number of structures of $n$ points would be $2^{n-1}-1$.

I would appreciate any help to prove (or disprove) the conjecture, discusse the inductive step sketch, and any hint of how (if possible) to proceed with the inductive step, using the sketch proposed or other better / simpler.

Thanks!

[1] *Chung, F. R. K.; Graham, R. L.*, [**Forced convex (n)-gons in the plane**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/PL00009353), Discrete Comput. Geom. 19, No. 3, 367-371 (1998). [ZBL0908.52004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0908.52004).

Comment: I'll take the opportunity to promote the work of Jineon Baek https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.04260 , who considers the structure of point configurations that avoid a-caps and b-cups. He shows that any $\binom{n-1}{2}+2$ points which have no $4$-cap must contain an $n$-gon. The key lemma (Theorem 5.10) is that a set of $\binom{n-1}{2}+2$ points with no $4$-cap and no $n$-cup must have two $(n-1)$-cups which relate in a certain way. So there is potential for results like "no a-caps and no b-caps force many b'-caps of a certain form".

Comment: @DavidESpeyer thanks for the reference! A very nice result, I will look at it thorougly